# window.addEventListener('load', function) not working in angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, addeventlistener, window-object, window-load

I have a subscription in a component of [angular](https://angular.io/) app where I need to download PDF file from response.

I am downloading PDF file after **window.open()** method has been called and later need to close current(new opened) tab via **window.close()** method.

**window.close()** method should run only after **load** event of `window` object is completed and PDF file is downloaded, but **load** event is not firing.

Here is code:

```
.subscribe(
    (res: any) => {
        if (response) {

                const formData: string = response.replace(/\n/g, '');
                const win: any = window.open('', '_blank'); // open new tab
                win.document.write(formData); 
                // NOT FIRED
                win.addEventListener('load', () => {
                    // submit form received in response
                        win.close();         // NOT CALLED
                    },
                    false
                    );
                    
                }
            }
        );
```

***Note:** I don't want to use setTimeout() function and call window.close() there since
the time for downloading might vary based on different factors (such as browser environment, file size and et.c.),
otherwise it's possible to solve this issue by using:*

```
    win?.setTimeout(() => {
        win?.close();
    }, 3000);
```

So, what is wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it looks like you are adding the load listener on `window` and not on `win` which is probably what you want.

Here is the way I normally use.

I do not have a way to test this with pdf files, but the way I download files received with an http request is by using Blob. Like this:

```
const blob = new Blob([res], {type : 'application/pdf'});
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.open(url);
```

From my experience with other file types, this opens the tab, starts downloading the file and closes (while the file is still downloading).

Feel free to ask for clarification if needed!

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I made a mistake in a post, it is written `win` instead of `window`. I will update it. Unfortunately this approach will not suit.